# Issue on Ubuntu 16.04 - MySQL 5.7 - Access denied with all new users excluding root

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have set up new server with Ubuntu 16.04 and installed LEMP on it with MySQL 5.7. Everything is good excluding with MySQL login.

I can login with "root" by [mysql -u root -p] on command line or phpMyAdmin. But I don't want to use root, I have created new users like

> bill with hostname=localhost and grant basic permissions
>
> bill2 with hostname=% and grant full permissons

when I tried to connect from command line or phpMyAdmin, I got error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill2'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'bill2'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I tried research more time but I haven't fixed problem yet. Could you provide me any solutions, please? Thanks so much!

Thanks All :-)

**Updated 2018-07-13**:

I'm not sure why my question marked decreasing :-). Probably I missed noting that I tried with other solutions which I found from Google/Stackoverflow. Let me list some ways which I tried:

- I connected new user from localhost and by command line
- I used `-h` parameter when connecting
- I changed `bind-address` in config file with 127.0.0.1

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7, and I haven't got the issue like that

Comment: There are 2100+ existing posts found searching for **Access denied for user @'localhost' (using password: YES)** using the search box at the top of this page.

Comment: @KenWhite : thanks for your comment. And YES, I tried with any solutions which I found from Google or Stackoverflow. I have upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7, and I haven't got the issue like that. That's why I asked anybody who experienced same issue or have any idea. Anyway, thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should run this cmd in mysql command line.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

If you'd like to connect to mysql with remote computer, you should also vim the config file

`vim /etc/mysql/my.conf
 #bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was connecting from localhost via command line. I have used "-h" parameter also but I still got the issue. I also created new user with code which is similar your comment, but it didn't work. Hope you can find solution for it, for now I'm using "root" account :D